# Styling of widget titles Wordpress, Headway theme

Tags: wordpress, widget, styling

My website is www.herefordequestrian.co.uk
There is a Twitter widget on the left hand side and then a widget ready leaf in the centre of the page for latest ads and latest news.

Using visual editor in Wordpress (Headway theme), I want to control the styling of them  separately, but can't!

I'm trying to get rid of the background colour behind the Twitter heading of 'Latest Tweets' but I want to retain the background colour behind the widget titles 'Latest Ads' and 'Latest News'.

Also, I'd like the hyperlinks in the 'Latest Ads and News' section to be in bold, but not in the Twitter column.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!
Sally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can target the Twitter widget's title like this:

```
#twitter-4.widget_twitter .widget-title {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I've just done that and it hasn't changed it?

Comment: Try the revised version - the first version I posted may not have been specific enough.

Comment: Further to this, I realise now that some of my other widget titles have a background colour instead of a transparent colour. Presumably I use the following code on all of them, but with the widget title named at the beginning of the code. So how do I find out the name of each individual title?  .widget-title {
  background-color: transparent;
}

Comment: If you're using Chrome, Safari, or Firefox you can easily right-click and element and choose "inspect element" to get the class/ID name.